# 401 unauthorised error while connecting to SAP Restful services API

Tags: c#, rest, postman, restful-authentication, sap-gateway

We have a **SAP RESTful service** for retrieving Order details from SAP. When I test the URL from **Postman its working fine**. I am able to see the expected records. But when I am trying to do the same from C#, its throwing unauthorised error. I have used the code generated from postman.

I am not sure how to connect to a SAP restful service from c#. I have tried with the following code which is generated from Postman

```
var client = new RestClient("http://<ourserver>/sap/opu/odata/sap/test_WS2SERVICE/OrderSearch?&$filter=<query>&$format=json");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);  
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic <bearertoken>");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

When I execute this code, I am getting below response from the service:

> 401-Unauthorised

Not sure how this could be fixed. please let me know, how can we consume SAP Restful services in C#?

Comment: I don't have the answer, but have you tried installing/running fiddler and then check to see what the differences between the postman post and your post are?

Comment: check for the headers, how they are different in both these cases. https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Getting-Started

Comment: i have compared both the headers... Except user agent information, rest all other are exactly same..    for Postman it is like User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36

Comment: for rest sharp User-Agent: RestSharp/105.2.3.0... thats all the difference :(

Comment: Just to be sure: does your bearer token follow the base 64(username:password) format?